# How to get FullName as TestName in NUnit

Tags: c#, testing, nunit

I have an abstract test class, that contains test methods. Then some classes that derive from this abstract class. The TestExplorer recognizes the class deriving from abstract class structure, but the testNames are only with abstract class.
I would need to show NUNIT the fullName of test method, including the class, not only the abstract name.

- the TestName pattern {M}{a} gives me: NUnitTestProject1.Tests.Test1("hello")
- the FullName would be: NUnitTestProject1.NUnitTestProject1.Tests+TestImplement.NUnitTestProject1.Tests.NUnitTestProject1.Tests.Test1("hello")

I am missing the "TestImplementation1" class name.
How can I tell NUnit to show the Full name as TestName (i need the "Tests+TestImplement1" information)? Great would be something global like runsettings file.
[TestExplorerView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MaTNy.png).
I tried different nunit patterns, also runsettings file with `<DisplayName>FullNameSep</DisplayName>`.

thanks in advance!

simplyfied test class:

```
public abstract class Tests
{

    public class TestImplement1 : Tests
    {
    }

    public class TestImplement2 : Tests
    {
    }

    [Test]
    [TestCase("hello", TestName = "{M}{a}")]
    public void Test1(string param1)
    {
        Assert.Pass();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice question!

I think what you're trying doesn't work, as the NUnit VS Adapter doesn't make use of "Test Names" in the NUnit sense. I'm not 100% sure on the history here, but I think it's because the Visual Studio side of the Test Explorer can't handle tests with the same name.

<s>Instead, try looking at the [DefaultTestNamePattern](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/vs-test-adapter/Tips-And-Tricks.html) setting in the .runsettings file. The different options for patterns are defined on [this page of the docs](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/running-tests/Template-Based-Test-Naming.html) - I expect what you want `{C}+{M}{a}` - might need a bit of experimentation to get it exactly right.</s>

As pointed out by the @pwasap4 - these exact format created by NUnit as a tests full name isn't currently accessible through the pattern functionality. It may well be possible for someone to add this feature however.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I tried all the provided [patterns](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/running-tests/Template-Based-Test-Naming.html), but for example `{C}+{M}{a}` also gives me just the Test containing class only (the abstract again):  `NUnitTestProject1.Tests+NUnitTestProject1.Tests.Test1("hello")`. Whereas `TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.FullName` would contain the correct info `NUnitTestProject1.Tests+TestImplement1.Test1("hello")`, but i can't get it by patterns...

Comment: Ah - I've dug a bit deeper. It seems the test name you're after is generated by custom NUnit code in `TypeHelper.GetDisplayName` ([link](https://github.com/nunit/nunit/blob/6f8922423946901148c7a6ede6b9195ab4fea1f2/src/NUnitFramework/framework/Internal/TypeHelper.cs#L50)), which isn't currently exposed through any pattern. This may be a feature that's fairly possible to add to NUnit however, if you were interested.

Comment: thanks again for your effort! i'm fairly new to all that, but I think I will give it a try.

Comment: No problem! I suggest filing an issue first, so the framework team can review. But if they agree, I'm sure the contribution would be welcome!

Comment: filed a [bug](https://github.com/nunit/nunit/issues/3671). Temporary solved my issue by using ´[Category]´ attribute on my implementation classes.